# Does the holodeck safety limit change?

Tags: star-trek, holodeck

Simple question, but does the safely limits in the holodeck change for who's is in it.

For example, if Data and Wesley were running one of Worf's combat programs would there be different safety levels for both or a default max level for both.

A standard default would be dangerous if Naomi Wildman was in there running a combat program for adults

Comment: There were many examples of crew members customizing programs in the holodeck. The answer is therefore that the default would be a very low danger setting that individuals like Worf could manually raise. But I do not feel like searching through episode records on the internet to assemble the documentation required to post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

All evidence I have seen is that the default for the holodeck was to prevent major injury to the entity using it or the ship (there is at least one example of a holodeck blowing a hole in the wall with the safety off).  So the safety level would be a default based on the entities in the simulation.  As far as challenge levels, those were generally shown to be user controlled.  Wesley could jump into Worf's sim and he would get tossed around up until the computer thought he would get hurt beyond some level that seems universal (unless changed by the individual with sufficient permissions).  Data would jump in and have to manually up the level until he felt challenged or the ship similarly felt his life/limb was threatened.

https://books.google.com/books?id=cbYf2l7gczUC&pg=PT739&lpg=PT739&dq=star+trek+holodeck+safety+limit&source=bl&ots=lFuRG8nZWx&sig=et0u32e5elJFArsgbkSyV_Csvcg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwispN2sufvUAhULbz4KHZTvB5cQ6AEIVDAI#v=onepage&q=star%20trek%20holodeck%20safety%20limit&f=false

https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/5qn8jc/star_trek_the_holodeck_safety_protocols_are_more/